# In ASP.NET 7.0 returning an image using return File() does not close the connection

Tags: asp.net-core

### EDIT: After some more research I have discovered this is only a problem when using https. If I use http the connection is closed as expected. I have also tried multiple browsers but they all behave the same. I have also tried using curl and wget, they download the image and close the process, but running curl with the --trace flag leaves the following message at the end of the trace: `== Info: Connection #0 to host localhost left intact`

I'm currently using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` shoehorned into ASP.NET 7.0 to try to rewrite an old part of an application. This includes rendering the output to the browser. I have the following controller method:

```cs
public IActionResult Graph(int id)
{
    var ant = RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(3, 7);
    using var testGraph = new MyCustomChart(85, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < ant; i++)
    {
        testGraph.AddUnit(i, $"Unit {i}", RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(0,101)); 
    }
    var bytes = testGraph.Render(0, 0, ChartImageFormat.Png);
    return File(bytes, "image/png");
}
```

Which generates a chart with between 3 and 6 bars, with results ranging from 0 to 100. `MyCustomChart` is a wrapper built around the native library, but it doesn't do anything with it until I call the `.Render()` method. The `.Render()` method takes 3 parameters, of which currently only the ChartImageFormat one is used in the method. The two others are width and height but I have them hardcoded for testing purposes. Here is the `.Render()` method without all the chart-building stuff.

```cs
public byte[] Render(int width, int height, ChartImageFormat fmt)
{
  using var chart = new Chart();
  Chart.Size = new Size(1024, enheter.Count * 100);

  // snipped away lots of chart building code

  using MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
  Chart.SaveImage(imageStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
  return imageStream.ToArray();
}
```

I have tried both with and without `using` on `Chart()` and same result.

What currently happens is that if I use this enpoint in a `<img>` tag, the charts show up nice and without issues. Except that the browser does not stop loading. If I stop loading using the "X" in Chrome, the nice charts dissapear and gets replaced with the "image not found"-graphic.

If I just open the enpoint directly, I also get a nice graph, but the browser never stops loading.

I run the app using `dotnet run` and it does not log any errors, however it does not log the calls to the `Graph()` endpoint either, but that may be default behaviour for returning File data?

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening?

I have attached a GIF showing the issue... You can't see my cursor but I keep clicking reload and stop.

[image: Screen recording of issue]

Comment: Have you tried with another browser?disable the plugin you've installed?

Comment: Expanded question with answer.